# Editar arquivos locais sem precisar fazer commit

Tags: git, commit

Em um projeto existem alguns arquivos que necessitam de edição para rodar o servidor local, como `.htaccess`, `config.php`, entre outros.

Na `branch master`, mantemos estes arquivos com os dados em produção. Há alguns colaboradores que possuem configurações diferentes para rodar um servidor localmente, então cada um trabalha com dados diferentes em alguns arquivos.

Neste caso, gostaria de manter configurado pra minha máquina local alguns arquivos sem a necessidade de fazer `commit` deles e não "bagunçar" o código da `branch master` num eventual `merge`.

O `.gitignore` deleta estes arquivos no repositório. Há alguma outra solução? Como é o método de trabalho de vocês para solucionar este problema?

Comment: Você poderia colocar um `pre-commit hook` pra remover os arquivos de um eventual `commit`. 

Referência (Inglês): http://githooks.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O standard/ideal é dizer ao git para não seguir modificações desses ficheiros. Isso faz-se com o commando:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

O ficheiro vai continuar a fazer parte do repositório, mas as alterações locais não serão consideradas durante o commit.

Quando quiseres que o git volte a seguir modificacoes, usa a flag `--no-assume-unchanged`:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>
```

Comment: Parece coerente esta solução, mas não entendi como trabalhar com branchs já criadas. Posso user o comando nos arquivos na branch master, por exemplo, e a partir dai as branchs novas já estarão com este efeito?
Notei que em algumas branchs, mesmo usando este comando, pede para dar commit nos arquivos. Sendo que os mesmos não aparecem no "git status".

Comment: @TiagoAlves O comando não está relacionado com nenhum branch em particular. Alterações do ficheiro vão ser ignoradas durante o commit, independentemente do branch. Outra nota importante: isto apenas afecta a configuração local do git. Ou seja, outros developers terão de executar o mesmo comando se quiserem.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria criar um diretório onde colocaria os arquivos necessários em execução e exclui-lo com o `.gitignore`.

Por exemplo, criar um diretório chamado `build` e ao lançar a execução, mover todos os arquivos para este diretório. Assim preservando os dados originais dos arquivos, permitindo a edição deles e sem criar o risco deles serem adicionados ao commit acidentalmente.